# Why does type error show up even when there are no equal variable and function names?

Tags: python

I am having trouble regarding the Type Error. The function and variable names are not equal but its still giving me a Type Error.

```
def space():
    spaces=' '
    sp=print(spaces,end=' ')
    return(sp)

def inc_num():
    incr_num=print(num,end='  ')
    return(incr_num)

def dec_num():
    decr_num=print(k,end='  ')
    k=k-1
    return(decr_num)

def forward_pyramid():
    no_of_rows=int(input("Enter the number of rows for the pyramid:"))
    for row in range(1,no_of_rows):
        for space in range(1,no_of_rows-row):
            s=space()
            return(s)
        for num in range(1,row,1):
            n=inc_num()
            return(n)
        for k in range(row,0,-1):    
            m=dec_num()
            return(m)

forward_pyramid()
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA0H1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please don't SHOUT!

Comment: You should avoid using pictures in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a variable and function with the same name (`space`). On that line, space is an int.

Change line 16:

```
    for space in range(1,no_of_rows-row):
```

To something else:

```
    for sp in range(1,no_of_rows-row):
```

And your error goes away.